# How to insert new item into dictionary to the end in ts/js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

I have a dictionary e.g.

```
let dict = { 'aa': 1, 'bb': 2 };
```

When I insert a new item:

```
dict['11'] = 3
```

it goes to the start:

```
{11: 3, aa: 1, bb: 2}
```

Are there any way insert to the end?

The object comes from API call, so this is how it looks like initially - not Map or Dictionary object.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It's not a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (and those _do_ preserve insertion order)

Comment: But nor is it a "dictionary" OP, it's a vanilla object and those aren't semantically ordered data structures. What's the context - why does the "first" key matter?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the order is important since it displayed to user in this order, and when he creates a new key - it must be the last in order.

Comment: Then if it's coming via JSON you need a different data structure, maybe an array of objects or [key, value] pairs (with which you can easily construct a proper Map client-side).

Comment: JS puts everything than can be a number before any other string, don't ask why.
If you want insertion order, either add a prefix or use a Map.

Comment: You're mixing up data display concerns with data storage concerns to achieve false economy.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - do you mean I must store separately dictionary and array of order of keys?

Comment: Probably. Depending on how generic your front end is, you might maintain the field order in the view rendering logic. If your back end needs to provide the ordering, you could return it as an additional view model property.

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN's [Objects vs Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps) documentation:

In regards to a `Map`:

> *The keys in `Map` are ordered in a simple, straightforward way: A `Map` object iterates entries, keys, and values in the order of entry insertion.*

In regards to an `Object`:

> *Although the keys of an ordinary `Object` are ordered now, this was not always the case, and the order is complex. As a result, it's best not to rely on property order.*
>
> *The order was first defined for own properties only in ECMAScript 2015; ECMAScript 2020 defines order for inherited properties as well. But note that no single mechanism iterates all of an object's properties; the various mechanisms each include different subsets of properties. (`for-in` includes only enumerable string-keyed properties; `Object.keys` includes only own, enumerable, string-keyed properties; `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` includes own, string-keyed properties even if non-enumerable; `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` does the same for just Symbol-keyed properties, etc.)*

So, if you want to represent the `Map` in insertion-order, you will need to iterate over it. If you convert the map to an `Object`, you lose the order.

```js
const dict = { 'aa': 1, 'bb': 2 };

const map = new Map(Object.entries(dict));

map.set('11', 3); // Last item in Map, but first in an Object

// Iterate over insertion order...
console.log('1.) Iterate over map');
for (let [key, value] of map) {
  console.log(`${key} => ${value}`)
}

// Or iterate through the keys, and access the corresponding value
console.log('2.) Iterate over keys');
for (let key of map.keys()) {
  console.log(`${key} => ${map.get(key)}`)
}

console.log('3.) Convert to Object, unordered');
console.log(Object.fromEntries(map.entries())); // Unordered
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

### If order matters from back-end to front-end

If the order matters, you need to change the way the server and client interact:

```js
const serverData = `[["aa",1],["bb",2]]`; // Entry/tuple array from server

// Transform: JSON entry pairs (key, value) -> Map
const fromServerData = (json) => JSON.parse(json)
  .reduce((m, [k, v]) => m.set(k, v), new Map);

// Transform: Map -> JSON entry pairs (key, value)
const toServerData = (map) => JSON.stringify([...map.entries()]);

// Parsed from tuple array JSON into Map object
const clientData = fromServerData(serverData);

// Convenience for adding to tuple to underlaying Map
const addToClientData = ([key, value]) => clientData.set(key, value);

addToClientData(['11', 3]); // Add data tuple

// Iterate (key insertion order) over Map
for (let [key, value] of clientData) {
  console.log(`${key} => ${value}`);
}

// Transform to back into JSON
const updatedServerData = toServerData(clientData);

console.log(updatedServerData); // Preserve order of Map as tuple array
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: So, the only way is to convert original dictionary into Map object, insert new item and then back - convert into dictionary to pass as json  object?

Comment: @SergeyCh. I added a transformation example from server to client and back to server; at the end of my response.